# PHP Coffee Cup Web Form

Tags: php, html, iframe

Hi guys I am really struggling here trying to get my coffee cup web form to display on my website :(  I've put in the code it generates

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(unescape("%3Ciframe id=\"fb_iframe\" src=\"contactform.php" + window.location.search + "\" width=\"100%\" height=\"714\"allowtransparency=\"true\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"%3E&lt;a href=\"contactform.php\" title=\"contactform\"&gt;Check out my CoffeeCup       Form&lt;/a&gt;%3C/iframe%3E"));</script>
<noscript>
<iframe width="100%" height="714" style="border:none; background:transparent;      overflow:hidden;"
id="fb_iframe" src="contactform/contactform.html">
&lt;a href="contactform.php" title="contactform"&gt;Check out my CoffeeCup
Form&lt;/a&gt;
</iframe>
</noscript>
```

And uploaded the files and I can see it here:

http://gpheatingandgas.co.uk/contactform.php

But not here:

http://gpheatingandgas.co.uk/contact_test.html

Would be great if you can help me and prevent me from tearing my hair out :)

Kind regards

Priesty

Comment: Did you develop the code for the form yourself, or use a template?

Comment: Template using Coffee Cup Web Form builder and the site it self I used a template.  :(

Comment: There is probably a better solution, but have you tried copying and pasting the code for the form inside the contact_test.html page, rather than using a script?

Comment: :S Beats me, Just done what the bit of software says, paste code and upload files which i've done but where im trying to have the form display it wont :(

Comment: Is there anything I need to put before and after?

Comment: no I don't think so, on the contactform page copy the html from <html> to </html> and paste it exactly where you want it to go, in the html of contact_test

Comment: I am not an expert, there is bound to be a better answer out there. This just might work.

Comment: Tried that :( seems were so close, its displays it lovely in my preview, but when I upload it and try it, it's still missing - I did overwrite it and also uploaded with another name but still missing, why O why

Comment: http://gpheatingandgas.co.uk/images/screenshot.png

Comment: Are you able to provide the code for each of the pages? I will try to work it on JSfiddle